# MYSQL query not the result I looking for

Tags: php, mysql

I have this query:

```
SELECT gamer_id,COUNT(*) AS sum, SUM(amount) as amount 
        FROM sales_list 
        WHERE rdate BETWEEN '2012-04-01' AND '2012-04-30' AND gamer_id NOT IN 
            (SELECT gamer_id FROM sales_list WHERE rdate < '2012-04-01' GROUP BY gamer_id) 
        GROUP BY gamer_id
```

This query printed me "2" results and I'm looking just "1".

I have 1 gamer's that deposit 2 times in April and I don't want to count the total deposits just to count the total gamer's that deposited.

any advice?

Comment: Surely that's just the number of records in your resultset?  Or do you not want to show each gamer as a separate record?

Comment: please provide inputs and desire out put

Comment: added: probably you dont required inner query thanks

Comment: @MoyedAnsari Why not? The conditions change if you leave it out.

Comment: the force is strong with MySQL...

Comment: So you get two rows of results? Or do you get one row with `COUNT(*)` value of 2? If you want the total number of unique gamer_ids you can just count the number of rows.

Comment: yeah the COUNT(*) value is "2" and I need the count will be 1, because, even if the gamer deposit 50 times a month, I want to get him 1 times, The result should print just the number of new traders that deposited...

Comment: Just check the number of returned rows and leave `COUNT(*)` out completely.

Comment: 6 comments until a Star Wars joke...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't really get it, but you want the numbers of deposits of a gamer only or the amount he deposited in addition?!

This should deliver number of deposits:

```
SELECT gamer_id, COUNT(gamer_id) AS sum, SUM(amount) as amount 
FROM sales_list 
WHERE rdate BETWEEN '2012-04-01' AND '2012-04-30'
GROUP BY gamer_id
HAVING COUNT(gamer_id)>0
```

Edit:

```
SELECT DISTINCT gamer_id
FROM sales_list 
WHERE rdate BETWEEN '2012-04-01' AND '2012-04-30' 
AND gamer_id NOT IN  (SELECT gamer_id 
                      FROM sales_list 
                      WHERE rdate < '2012-04-01') 
GROUP BY gamer_id
```

Comment: something like that, but, I want those things in the query:
1. The total Unique Sum gamer's
2. check if they not deposited before (just the new gamer's)

Comment: Argl, so you want just new id of new games in that month, regardless how often they deposit and only once. This is different what you asked at 1st place. Then no COUNT(), I edit my post and add this.

Comment: Btw, It's possible to get also the SUM of their deposit's amount in the same query?

Comment: As SUM(amount) as amount is DISTINCT also you should be able to just add it.

Comment: yeah but I get now just the amount of the first row of the table, I'm not getting the sum of all traders..

Comment: You want the amount of only the new gamer then in one select? Try add column-subselect: (SELECT SUM(amound) FROM sales_list s2 WHERE s2.gamer_id = sales_list.gamer_id AND rdate BETWEEN '2012-04-01' AND '2012-04-30') AS total_gamer_sum

Answer (score 0):

try this:

```
SELECT sl.gamer_id,COUNT(*) AS sum, SUM(sl.amount) as amount 
        FROM sales_list sl
        WHERE sl.rdate BETWEEN '2012-04-01' AND '2012-04-30' AND sl.gamer_id NOT IN 
            (SELECT sl1.gamer_id FROM sales_list sl1 WHERE sl1.rdate < '2012-04-01' GROUP BY sl1.gamer_id) 
        GROUP BY sl.gamer_id
```